# Consuming Webservices in a Domino clustered environment

Tags: web-services, cluster-computing, lotus-domino

Trying to consume a non Domino WS via native `Web Service Consumers` but keep getting

`Error connecting to '10.46.180.11' on port '80', The destination network is unreachable.` when i run it.

If i stop the cluster-port on the server/s- console the Web Service **works fine!?**
Also if the cluster-port is on - it works to consume the Web service via COM/Lotusscript.

The environment consists of three `8.53fp3/win64 servers` in a `Domino Cluster` (not ICM).

***The cluster config:***

`Server cluster probe count: 5343

Server cluster default port: CLUSTER

Server cluster auxiliary ports: TCPIP

Server availability threshold: 0

Server availability index: 99 (state: AVAILABLE)

Server availability default minimum transaction time: 3000

Cluster members (3):

Server: server1, availability index: 98

Server: server2, availability index: 61

Server: server3, availability index: 41`

There is no blocking in the firewall!

Comment: Are you able trace route to that IP from the machine executing the consumer? Is your proxy set up correctly for that server?